# Convert to a complete date in c#

Tags: c#, date

I have the date in this format: `MMyyyy`.

I need convert to the format: `yyyyMMdd`

I tried this:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(monthyear, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

Did not work.

Comment: Well first off, how do you pan to get the day from data that does not have a day in it?

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work?"

Comment: I thought the C # put the first day of the month

Comment: I mean... i need this: `yyyymmdd` from `mmyyyy`

Comment: @novato But you're telling it to parse as yyyymmdd, not mmyyyy, or more correctly MMyyyy

Comment: @Jacobr365 It is the first day of the month by default.

Comment: `mm` means minutes

Comment: Yes.. i've edited ... its Months not minutes

Comment: Show us an example value of `monthyear`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .NET DateTime string formats, `mm` stands for minutes and `MM` stands for month. Also, the format you pass to the Parse is the existing format and not the output format. So you should use:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(monthyear, "MMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

string result = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

So you're asking the API to Convert a String which is in the `"MMyyyy"` format to a `DateTime` object. Then you use the `DateTime`'s `.ToString()` method to convert it to the desired string representation format which is `"yyyyMMdd"`.

The `Day` part of the `DateTime` would be default to the first day of the month since it is not provided in your string representation.

Answer (score 4):

First: You can not derive a day from a string that doesn't have a day in it, so you need to parse using a format that does not expect a day.

Second: `mm` stands for minutes in date format strings. `MM` is for months.

So you should try this:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(monthyear, "MMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
            DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
string result = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

The first will create a datetime variable from your source string, the second will create the desired format from that.

Comment: so what you need is  `DateTime.TryParseExact("01" + monthyear, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);`

Comment: It should be the first of the month by default.

Comment: Tested it and yes, you are correct, did not know that... Docs say that if date is not present in string TryParseExact assumes DateTime.Now.Date but I guess they mean only when no portion of a date is present, not just when the day of month portion is missing. THx!

Answer (score 2):

As Thorsten Dittmar pointed out your input value should contain day value as well.

```
monthyear += "01"

// now your input is in MMyyyydd format

DateTime date = null;

DateTime.TryParseExact(monthyear, "MMyyyydd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

string result = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: Parsing works even if the day is not part of the string. It would be defaulted into the first day of the month.